# How does AngularJS $watch these cases in an ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I understand that AngularJS sets up some watches on ng-repeat.  What type of watch is setup at this point?

Also, can someone explain what happens in each of these scenarios?  I want to know in the event that I have many items, so the user isn't being bogged down by watches that could have been eliminated had I written it some other way.

One

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <div>{{item.property}}</div>
</div>
```

Two

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <div>{{item.property | myFormatter}}</div>
</div>
```

Three

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <div>{{format(item.property)}}</div>
</div>
```

Four

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <div>{{item.something()}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each `ng-repeat` will set up a $watch on `items`.  (If you look at the [ng-repeat source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/4efda14b499fa1dbc115f17bb3bf42385a00e239/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js#L92), most of it is the watchExpression function of the $watch method).  Each time an Angular [digest cycle](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#runtime) runs, each `item` in `items` will be examined by this watch function.  (Note that in a digest cycle, this watch function could be called more than once).

Each `{{}}` sets up a $watch.  If something like `item.property` is inside the {{}}s, it is dirty checked at least once per digest cycle.

If a function is inside {{}}s, then that function is called at least once per digest cycle.

I'm not sure about `x | filter`, but [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/R3ZsC/) seems to indicated that the filter is called at least once every digest cycle, even if `x` doesn't change.

Comment: That's crazy about `x | filter`.  I don't understand why that is.  Maybe they assume filter is not going to be a pure function?

Comment: I was quite surprised by that also.

Comment: Updated link for the ng-repeat source code: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.6.x/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js. Looks like they now use $watchCollection to do shallow checks. Thank you Mark!